# How to search a json array for some items with a certain key?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Table: some_table, Records:

```
id|data (json array of json object)
1|[{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}]
2|[{"a": 5, "b": 6}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}]
```

Would u show me the SQL (MySQL), to find any record whose data has a item (with a key "a" and value 5). Only record #2 will be found. I tried the following SQL but failed, because I'm new to use SQL for JSON.

```
select * from some_table where json_contains(data, '5', '$.a') = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, data
from
(
select 1 as id, '[{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}]' as data
union select 2 as id, '[{"a": 5, "b": 6}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}]' as data
) as tmp
where json_contains(data -> '$[*].a','5')
```

Comment: Thank u very much, and I just figured out the same solution as yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two fundamental flaws in your current SQL statement:

1. For checking if keys exist in a JSON document, you'll want to utilize [`json_contains_path()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains-path) as opposed to `json_contains()`, which will allow you to specify a specific key path without actually having to provide a value for which you're looking for said key.
2. The `path` you're leveraging to look for key `a` doesn't respect that that key would be contained within an array structure - you need to modify your `path` to look everywhere in the document for a key `a`. (H/T to [MySQL :: MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual :: 11.6 The JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-path-syntax))

With this knowledge, your query would now look like this:

```
select * from some_table where json_contains_path(data, 'one', '$**.a')
```

which, utilizing your sample dataset, returns:

```
+----+--------------------------------------+
| id |                 data                 |
+----+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}] |
|  2 | [{"a": 5, "b": 6}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}] |
+----+--------------------------------------+
```

<sup>[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sjjJDugcpr4wZL7AZbGavT/1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your helping. I just tried your SQL above, but I got an error: `ERROR 3143 (42000): Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 2.` Do you have any idea?

Comment: My mistake - it appears the JSONPath implementation in MySQL 8.0 doesn't support the double dot `..` selector. Please see updated path selector in my answer above (`**`).

Comment: It worked this time and I got the result above. Now I got any record whose data contains a item with key "a", what should I do next to filter them and only get those value w.r.t. key "a" is 5? I tried `select * from some_table where json_contains(data, '5', '$**.a') = 1;` and got `ERROR 3149 (42000): In this situation, path expressions may not contain the * and ** tokens or an array range.`.

Comment: Thanks man! I used json_extract and json_contains and I succeeded. `select * from some_table where json_contains(data->"$**.a", '5');`

Comment: @painterdrown Great to hear!